# Stripe Error "please insert a valid credit card expiration date"

Tags: magento2, payment

I'm using magento 2 and I've managed to install Stripe Payment Gateway , but now when I go on the checkout page and insert the credit card data and try to pay , I get please "insert a valid credit card expiration date".
I have tryed also with other cards, so is not a credit card issue.

Comment: Ask the extension creator about your issue, and specifically to verify compatibility with the latest version of Magento.

Comment: I have already wrote to extension creators , haven't got any reply yet..

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a "please insert a valid credit card expiration date" error message when trying to pay with Stripe on your Magento 2 store, there are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

- Double-check the expiration date: Ensure that the expiration date you are entering is correct, and that it is not expired. The expiration date should be entered in the MM/YY format.
- Check your Stripe account settings: Verify that your Stripe account settings are configured correctly. Make sure that your account is in live mode if you are testing with a real credit card.
- Ensure that your server time is accurate: Stripe validates the expiration date of the credit card based on the time on your server. If your server time is not accurate, you may receive an error. Check the date and time settings on your server to ensure they are correct.
- Clear cache and reindex: Clear the Magento cache and reindex the website to ensure that the latest settings are being used.
- Contact Stripe support: If the above steps do not resolve the issue, reach out to Stripe support for further assistance.